# Synchronize QTableWidget cell with widget in the center of the cell

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qt-signals, qcheckbox

I use `QCheckBox` in `QTableWidgetCell`

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(checkBox);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
widget->setLayout(layout);
table->setCellWidget(0, 0, widget);
```

The result of this code is a cell with checkbox in the center.

I need to make checkbox reaction to mouse moving and clicking in the empty area like when cursor is under checkbox.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the fullblown functionality of `QCheckBox` but just the checkmark, You can use a simple `QTableWidgetItem` and modify his checkstate.

```
QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
table->setItem ( 0, 0, item );

connect(table, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int , int )), this, SLOT(OnClicked( int, int)));


void OnClicked( int row, int column )
{
   if(row != checkablelerow && col != checkablelecol )
     return; // or do something else

   item = table->item(row, column);

   item->setCheckState(item->checkState() == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked);
}
```

Now the whole cell will be checkable. Code may need refinement.

Comment: I don't understand what does mean fullblown functionality. What I need is when cursor in empty area checkbox is highlighting, when lmb is down checkbox is in pushed state.

Comment: I say  fullblown functionality because a checkbox is a `QAbstractButton` (a Qwidget)

Answer (score 0):

You can override eventFilter method to highlight your checkbox when cursor enters the cell. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter

```
bool ExampleDialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
         {
             if (qobject_cast<QTableWidgetItem*>(object)) {
                 if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter) {
                     QCheckBox* qcb = object->findChild<QCheckBox*>();
                     //here you can do something to highlight your checkbox
                     return true;
                 }
                 else if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverLeave){
                     QCheckBox* qcb = object->findChild<QCheckBox*>();
                     //here you have to stop highlighting checkbox
                      return true;
                 } 
                 else {
                     return false;
                 }
             }
         }
```

After overriding, you have to install event filter on your widgets like this

```
 widget->installEventFilter(this); //this points to parent of the widget, the exampleDialog
```

And use a clicked slot of  QTableWidgetItem* to set your checkbox checked.

```
void QTableWidgetItemClicked( int row, int column )
{
    QCheckBox* qcb = QObject::sender()->findChild<QCheckBox*>();
    qcb->setChecked(!qcb->isChecked());
}
```

Remember to connect QTableWidgetItems signals to slots.

Comment: `if (qobject_cast<QTableWidgetItem*>(object))` - error C2039: 'qt_metacall' : is not a member of 'QTableWidgetItem'

Comment: I replaced to dynamic_cast. Now it compiled but does not work.